# Error : Failed to read file - Terraform backend.tf file

Tags: azure, jenkins, terraform, backend

I have created Jenkins Pipeline to automate the infrastructure deployment using terraform which consists of 3 stages terraform init, terraform plan and terraform apply.

While executing the pipeline I encountered an error as below:-

[image]

Am unable to understand what is the error and why it is occurred.

If I run the same configuration and terraform code in my local device, it works fine and successful.

But if I run the same using Jenkins pipeline, its giving me an error.

Below is the folder structure I have created for terraform:-

[image]

Am trying to execute the terraform config using the below commands:-

```
terraform init -backend-config=../environment/$params.location/$params.env/backend.tf  -backend-config="subscription_id="$ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID""

terraform plan -var-file=../environment/$params.location/$params.env/terraform.tfvars

terraform apply -var-file=../environment/$params.location/$params.env/terraform.tfvars
```

Can anyone assist me to understand where am I going wrong.
I have tried searching globally but of no use.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Please find the Jenkins Pipeline Code (Containers, Volume and Resources is been hidden from the code and it is working fine. Terraform init stage is failing):-

```
pipeline {
agent {
    kubernetes {
     yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            iac: labelbuild
        spec:
            containers:
                           

              resources:
                
              volumeMounts:
                 
            volumes: 
                
         '''
    }
}
environment {
        ARM = credentials("${params.Service_principal}")
}
parameters {
        choice(choices: '',            description: 'Select Location to Build', name: 'location')
        choice(choices: '', description: 'Select Env to Build',      name: 'env')
        string(name: 'Service_principal', defaultValue: '',                        description: 'Enter the Service principal ID for ex : ngpr-deploy-dev-sp'  )
        string(name: 'repo_url',    defaultValue: '',    description: 'Enter the Infra repo http URL'  )
        string(name: 'Branch_Name', defaultValue: '',    description: 'Enter the Infra repo URL Branch to build'  )
}

/* Terraform stages will be running to excute the scripts from the repository and deploy it in the Azure portal */

stages {

    stage ('terraform init') {
        steps{
            container('terraform') {
                sh """
                    
                    echo "Service_Principal Name is ${params.Service_principal}"
                    terraform version
                    curl ifconfig.me
                    ls -lat
                    pwd
                    cd terraform/source
                    rm -rf .terraform/
                    rm -f .terraform.lock.hcl
                    terraform init -backend-config=../environment/$params.location/$params.env/backend.tf  -backend-config="subscription_id="${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}""
                    
                  """
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage ('terraform validate') {
        steps {
            container('terraform') {
                sh """
                    cd terraform/source
                    terraform validate
                    """
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('terraform plan') {
        steps {
            container('terraform') {
                sh """
                     cd terraform/source
                     terraform plan -var-file=../environment/$params.location/$params.env/terraform.tfvars
                    """
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('terraform apply') {
        input {
            message "User input required"
            ok "Yes"
            parameters {booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'Choose "yes" if you want to apply this plan')}
        }
        steps{
                container('terraform') {
                  sh """
                    cd terraform/source  
                    terraform apply -var-file=../environment/$params.location/$params.env/terraform.tfvars
                   """
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We need to see the Jenkins Pipeline code.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Hello, I have added the Jenkins pipeline script. It is a very simple script which will be found anywhere on internet.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be due to a typo in the Jenkins script.  Screenshot shows "environments" (plural); Jenkins file shows "environment" (no "s" at the end).  The issue can be fixed by replacing the relevant references to "environment" in the Jenkins file with "environments".

Comment: Thankyou so much. Some times we involved so much into the technicality we tend to forget the common use cases. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Could you please assist on how to add email approvers list in terraform apply stage in the input parameter option